How to using the REST API to get the Json view from logic app connections
I want to use the rest api to modify the json view in the connections of the logic app (Type:Standard), but I don't know the corresponding API to implement it：

I using the develop tool to get the URL, but it does not work:
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<SubscriptionId>/resourceGroups/<ResourceGroups>/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/<LogicAppName>/deployWorkflowArtifacts?api-version=2018-11-01

Note:
Since the content in the json view is a lot and dynamic, I want use Get to get the content before modifying it, and then simply modify Json view with this body update to overwrite the original json view.
I am using Powershell as code scripts, a working example would be better.
So, my question is that is there a direct REST API to obtain and modify the Json view? If not, how do I get it?
Update1:
When I using the Az rest, I could not get the correct feedback, below is my test scripts:
$token = $(Token)
$header = @{authorization = "Bearer $token"}
$connectionsText = az rest --method get --uri https://<logic-app-name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/site/wwwroot/connections.json --resource "https://management.azure.com/" --headers "$header"

$connectionsObj = $connectionsText | ConvertFrom-Json
$connectionsObj | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name "TestName" -Value "TestValue"
$connectionsText = $connectionsObj | ConvertTo-Json

Write-Host "This is the json view:$connectionsText"

echo $connectionsText > connections.json

However, I get below feedback:


az rest example:
$connectionsText = az rest `
    --method get `
    --uri https://<logic-app-name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/site/wwwroot/connections.json `
    --resource https://management.azure.com/

$connectionsObj = $connectionsText | ConvertFrom-Json
$connectionsObj | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name "TestName" -Value "TestValue"
$connectionsText = $connectionsObj | ConvertTo-Json
echo $connectionsText > connections.json

az rest `
    --method put `
    --uri https://<logic-app-name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/site/wwwroot/connections.json `
    --body "@connections.json" `
    --resource https://management.azure.com/ `
    --headers If-Match=*


Since the content in the json view is a lot and dynamic, I don't want to make it completely fixed. So I will use Get to get the content before modifying it, and then simply modify it as a body update to overwrite the original json view. But do you have a practical example of how to get it? I changed the method you provided to GET, but I couldn't get the information I wanted.

Not sure why GET didn't work for you. I have tested and updated my answer.

I have updated my test answer in my posted, please check the update1 for some more details.

I used az rest for my convenience, you don't have to use it. I didn't use  --headers "$header" like you did, as I logged in using az login thus authentication was applied automatically, my account was used for testing. Try testing via curl or from Postman - you shouldn't have these Python errors there. I was able to send GET/PUT requests from Postman successfully. Let me know if it works for you.
